# Org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default not updating

Tags: updates

I am unable to complete updates to my newly installed Horus system.

Org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default will simply refuse to update.

Even via terminal.

I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following command via terminal to fix the issue:

pkexec flatpak repair

the command will remove the bad references from the ISO then re-install the correct references of the broken references for the flatpak modules